# Apache SSL config not listening on 443

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, httpd, httpd.conf

I am trying to setup an apache website for SSL with a self-signed cert. I setup the `vhost` and everything looks ok to me. But the site is not coming up and on the server itself port `443` is not listening.

Website: [https://beta.jokefire.com](https://beta.jokefire.com/)

VHOST config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
     SSLEngine On
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/beta.jokefire.com.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/beta.jokefire.com.key
     #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/root-certificate.crt  #If using a self-signed certificate or a root certificate provided by ca-certificates, omit this line

     ServerAdmin serveradmin@jokefire.com
     ServerName beta.jokefire.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/jf-beta
     ErrorLog logs/jf_beta.jokefire.com_ssl_error_log
     CustomLog logs/jf_beta.jokefire.com_ssl_access_log combine
</VirtualHost>
```

I am listening on port `80` but not on port `443`:

```
[root@web1:~] #lsof -i :80
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd   14489   root    4u  IPv6 1575659387      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   14490 apache    4u  IPv6 1575659387      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   14497 apache    4u  IPv6 1575659387      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   14497 apache   27u  IPv6 1575659779      0t0  TCP web1.jokefire.com:http->37.151.164.13.megaline.telecom.kz:54674 (ESTABLISHED)
httpd   14498 apache    4u  IPv6 1575659387      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   14499 apache    4u  IPv6 1575659387      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   14499 apache   27u  IPv6 1575659460      0t0  TCP web1.jokefire.com:http->7.bl.bot.semrush.com:23728 (ESTABLISHED)
httpd   14501 apache    4u  IPv6 1575659387      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   14502 apache    4u  IPv6 1575659387      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   14525 apache    4u  IPv6 1575659387      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   14541 apache    4u  IPv6 1575659387      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   14542 apache    4u  IPv6 1575659387      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
[root@web1:~] #lsof -i :443
[root@web1:~] #
```

Here's my cert and key and directories:

```
[root@web1:~] #ls -lh /etc/pki/tls/certs/beta.jokefire.com.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/beta.jokefire.com.crt
-rw-------. 1 root root 1.5K Oct 17 16:14 /etc/pki/tls/certs/beta.jokefire.com.crt
-rw-------. 1 root root 1.5K Oct 17 16:14 /etc/pki/tls/certs/beta.jokefire.com.crt

[root@web1:~] #ls -ld /etc/pki/tls/certs /etc/pki/tls/private/
drwx------. 2 root root 4096 Oct 17 16:20 /etc/pki/tls/certs
drwx------. 2 root root 4096 Oct 17 16:13 /etc/pki/tls/private/
```

And the SSL log files that I've defined in the apache `vhost` are there on the filesystem, but they are empty:

```
[root@web1:~] #ls -lh /var/log/httpd/jf_beta.jokefire.com_ssl_access_log /var/log/httpd/jf_beta.jokefire.com_ssl_error_log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct 17 16:36 /var/log/httpd/jf_beta.jokefire.com_ssl_access_log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct 17 16:36 /var/log/httpd/jf_beta.jokefire.com_ssl_error_log
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You also need `Listen 443` somewhere in your config.  On Debian, it's automatic if you have the SSL or GnuTLS modules enabled, for example; but other distros may differ.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot all about the listen command. D'OH! I've added it to my apache config and now it works. Thanks!